# How to get hornetq connetionfactory object using annotation

Tags: java, jms, jboss7.x, hornetq

My hornetq running in standalone mode.i need connectionfactory
 object using annotations.

Without annotations my code like this.

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Connection connection = null;
        InitialContext initialContext = null;
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;

        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhost:1099");
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        env.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,
            "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
        initialContext = new InitialContext(env);

        connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext
                .lookup("ConnectionFactory");

        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
                          }
```

Here I am able to get the connection object.

Using annotations my code like this.

```
    public class Test {

        @Resource(mappedName = "ConnectionFactory")
        private static  ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Connection connection = null;
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            }
            }
```

here I am getting connectionfactory object as null.

(annotation failed to lookup the connectionfactory)

Any one tell me the required configurations 
for getting the connnectionfactory object.its great help to me.

thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a Spring bean configuration containing the connection factory bean with the appropriate transport configurations.

[see this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/06/spring-3-hornetq-21-integration.html)

Comment: yeah, i read that with spring you can do it, but there is not specific annotations to do MDBs